# Verifying User Input

Tags: c#, text, textbox, verify

My user will enter some bytes in a place like this.

Yellow arrow points to his input, Orange arrow points to my button
[image: Screen Cap 001]

After about half an hour, I began to realize that this is far more tedious than I expected.

**Question:** Am I going to have to write hundreds of lines of code to ensure that the user follows the rules ?

The rules for the syntax in his input are...

- A hex byte
- Then a comma
- Then white space (maybe, at his option)

Those three rules can be repeated as much as the user wants. For received bytes, there are two more rules to handle...

- An Asterisk: wildcard which matches any number of bytes
- A question mark: wildcard which matches any one single byte

I have to check for

- Valid chars (0-9, A-F, upper/lower)
- The two wild cards  `?` and `*`
- Proper placement of commas
- No double commas
- Proper white space (e.g., none between digits)
- Aberrant white space (e.g., he can put zero, one, or multiple spaces after a comma)
- Possible single characters to represent a byte (e.g. "0" instead of "00")

Here are some examples..

(*First edit and update, all users are not created equal; the syntax checker must handle this*...)

**Nice Normal Neatly Formatted Input From Smart Good Users...**

- `01, FF, 3E, 27, 7F`
- `55, EE, 01, 00`
- `21, FE, 2B, 00, 1F`
- `37,  *, 18,  ?, 00, 37`
- `81,  *, 00,  *, FF, 91,  ?, 11,  ?, FF`
- `20, 31, 7F, 28,  *, FF`
- `47  4F, 20, 50, 4F, 4D, 45,  ?, 21`

**Ugly Sloppy Input From Stupid Bad Users...**

- `1,ff,3e,27,7f`
- `55,     EE,      1,    00`
- `21,Fe,    2b,0,    1f`
- `37,*,18,?,00,37`
- `81,  *, 0,  *,Ff, 91,?,11,    ?,FF`
- `20, 31,    7f, 28,  *,   FF`
- `47, 4F,   20,   50,4F,4D,45,  ?,21`

(*p.s., Stupid Bad Users sometimes put in ugly trailing spaces, and sometimes ugly leading spaces*)

Good grief this is getting hairy.  I'm up to three nested functions and I'm nowhere close to finished. I thought it was going to be a 20 minute typing exercise.

Has this problem already been solved before ?

Does *Visual Studio C#* already contain a property to demand only hex bytes separated by commas ?

Did I miss the obvious tree in the forest ?

The similar questions which were automatically suggested here on StackOverflow didn't really answer this, which surprises me. Certainly I'm not the first one to hit this annoyance. Suggestions welcome

Comment: It's called validation.  You could "simplify" it with a regex, if you know regex.  You can start by limiting typed input to your valid characters only.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that is a new phrase for me. Is it worth the education time to learn it ?

Comment: If your problem is that you have to write loads of imperative validation code in odd places, this would be an excellent time to make classes which represent your data (if you haven't already), and move your validation logic to those classes. That way validating your data is implicit in modifying or creating your data. It also looks like you're doing too much work to validate, regex is definitely worth learning (and not that hard). I'd recommend: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Comment: Just found this place, should I start studying here ?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Not sure how you're doing this but this is what I would do: **1)** Strip all whitespace, they're unnecessary anyway. **2)** Split the string in a array, delimited by a comma. **3)** Iterate over the array to check all characters are parsable to hex numbers. You can sandwich the wildcard checks along with the hex parsability check. Am I missing something? Or is that it?

Comment: @Asad, and RobertHarvey too, I'm off to that site Asad just suggested. Back in an hour

Comment: @Asad yes, this looks like the way to go. RobertHarvey and Asad for congress !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to do that:

```
String input = "01, FF, 3E, 27, 7F";
String pattern = @"^([0-9A-F]{2},\s?)*[0-9A-F]{2}$";

bool matches = Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern);
```

The regex is `^([0-9A-F]{2},\s?)*[0-9A-F]{2}$` which is

^ - beginning
[0-9A-F] - hex characters set
{2} - two characters of that set
, - just comma
\s? - optional space
* - repeated 0 or more times

Note: if you want to enforce a space after the comma, use `^([0-9A-F]{2},\s)*[0-9A-F]{2}$`

Note 2: if you want to allow only one character and allow lower case letters, use `^([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2},\s)*[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}$`

Comment: Oh yes !  Genius.  I will be examining this in detail. Thank you (a lot)

Comment: @Asad okay, reading your ideas with greater and greater interest every moment

Comment: @Asad True, changed that already in a different way (less compact but probably easier to understand).

Comment: @Asad Not sure what's required so added a note to the answer.

Comment: @Asad yes, it is (blush). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Asad  we have to let the user enter valid hex bytes, with two wildcards, `*` and `?`  it will get worse when the device responds, but for the moment `*` means anything in any amount, while `?` means anything in one byte

Comment: I'm getting an error: `Nested Quantifier +,`   I placed the line, `using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`  as the 8th line in my source code file. The 7th line was `using System.Text;`  This was with the input string `00, 01, FF`.  I get the same error when I click the button with no text in the textbox

Comment: Have you used the latest code from my answer? I updated it a few times.

Comment: Examining that now, it compiles and executes.  I will test it more over the next 10 minutes

Comment: Okay, here he gets confused:  He understands `00, 0F` but he thinks that `00, f` is an error.

Comment: Ok, see my second note. Didn't know you allowed lower case and only one character

Comment: You are correct. My original post left out significant and critical details.  I have edited it to be more comprehensive of the problem.

Comment: I'm off to study RegEx some more.  I will see if I can modify the pattern to accept zero, one, or more spaces between the comma and the next *Ascii_hex* byte (or whatever it's called).

Comment: how did you get that pattern to be case insensitive ?

Comment: Okay, so I observed (1) trailing spaces and (2) extra embedded spaces, to be non matching. Am I close with this altered pattern ?

`String pattern = @"^([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2},\s*)*[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}\s*$";`  I changed the first `\s?` to `\s*`  and then placed another `\s*` at the end of the pattern, and my initial tests indicate it works

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a non regex solution, you can use this. Regex are very powerful. If you start programming, maybe it is not the best approach. Regex can be a mess to read after shot. Use what you want and have fun.

Warning! This snippet dont check wild cards. I didn't know what you want to do with '?' and '*'.

You can try my code in this [Fiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/FewKBw).

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        bool b = checkValue("01, FF, 3E, 27, 7F");      // textBox.Text
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }

    static bool checkValue(string s)
    {
        string[] tab = s.Split(new string[] { ", " }, StringSplitOptions.None ); // split string with ", " as a delimiter
        foreach (var hex in tab)
        {
            if (hex.Length != 2) // Check if we have two values
                return false;
            foreach(var c in hex)
            {
                // check for valid letter (upper and lower) and digit
                if(!((c >= '0' && c <= '9') || 
                    (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') || 
                    (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')))
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

[Just read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773975/verifying-user-input/22774270#comment34721145_22773975) that @CPU-Terminator think about the same solution then me.