# Allowing Asterisks And Question Marks In A C# RegEx pattern

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

**QUESTION:** Where do I put the `*` or `\*` or `\\*` in a C# RegEx pattern to match asterisks in a target ?

Ditto for `\?` or `\\?`

*Details*...

I have an app which allows this kind of input

- One or two hex chars: `0-9`, or `a-f`, or `A-F`
- Then a mandatory comma: `,`
- Then optional white space (as much or as little  as desired, or none):

Shorthand description...

`0,` through `F,` as well as `00,` through `FF`, ignoring the case of the letters. Optional whitespace before and after are okay. The comma is required for delimiting, but not allowed on the end. (last char must be whitespace or end-of-text)

After that, the pattern can repeat as often as the user wants. (Whitespace does not have to balance.)

Example...

```
 00, F1, 33, A7,    21, 14, 0D, 0A, 30,30,30,31, 41,    3e,3e,3e,  41, 5A,   0
```

The following code works perfectly for this...

```
 private bool See_If_This_Input_Is_Okay(string The_Callers_Text)
    {
        String pattern = @"^\s*([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2},\s*)*[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}\s*$";

        bool matches = Regex.IsMatch(The_Callers_Text, pattern);

        return (matches);
    }
```

Now I want the pattern to accommodate...

- One or two adjacent asterisks, either: `*`  or `**`, Then a mandatory comma: `,`
- One or two adjacent question marks, either: `?`  or `??`, Then a mandatory comma: `,`

Shorthand description...

`0,` through `F,`  or  `00,` through `FF`, or `*,` or `**,` or `?,` or `??,`

(again with zero-to-random whitespace before and after [but not within] each string, commas enforced)

Example...

```
00, ??, 33, A7,    21, 14, ?,?, 30,30,30,31, **,    3e,3e,3e,  *, 5A,   0
```

After reading 20 or 30 similar posts here, I still cannot figure out where to place the `\*` and the `\?` sequence in the `pattern` string.

I also tried `\\*` and got nowhere.

That includes after the `f`, before the `$`, after the `s*` (either one) inside the brackets, outside the brackets; I suppose I could program my text editor to make fifty one copies of the line in question and try each position; but I really want to understand this, not just make it happen.

If anyone can explain what goes where, thanks, that will do. What I would really like to know is where this is explained and documented. I will leave out the dozen webpages I have visited which purport to explain this.

Thank you to anyone who can answer this.

Comment: `^\s*([0-9A-Fa-f\?\*]{1,2},\s*)*[0-9A-Fa-f\?\*]{1,2}\s*$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first, you could make the regex a little faster by changing the grouping a bit to:

```
@"^\s*[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}(,\s*[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}\s*)*$"
```

Now if you want to allow `*` and `?` as well, you could use something like this:

```
@"^\s*([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}|\*\*?|\?\??)(,\s*([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}|\*\*?|\?\??)\s*)*$"
```

I basically changed `[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}` to `([0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}|\*\*?|\?\??)`.

You might also use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` instead of using `A-Fa-f`:

```
String pattern = @"^\s*([0-9A-F]{1,2}|\*\*?|\?\??)(,\s*([0-9A-F]{1,2}|\*\*?|\?\??)\s*)*$";
bool matches = Regex.IsMatch(The_Callers_Text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Excellent again. Well duh; now I have to choose an answer, and you are both great.

Comment: @User.1 This one is perfect.

Comment: @SabujHassan yes, but look at my comments about your comments about Jerry's comments about... (now I know why they call it stack overflow).  Between the two of you, you have already improved my algorithm; in 20 minutes flat.

Comment: @User.1 Well, at least you have the options. The little grouping and alternation in my answer will not allow a hex with a wildcard, but I do advise for the change in grouping to raise the speed a bit!

Comment: Cool. Now, where do I learn all this ?  Is this something you just get out of your brain ?  I am ashamed to admit that I have spent this long (we're talking decades) and never looked at RegEx code before; never needed it before this week. Do you get this smart from (and only from) exercising it a thousand times in your brain ?

Comment: @User.1 Uh, regex was something I didn't quite understand at start, and I was learning my first prog. lang. at that time and was given something that used it. I kind of made myself learn the basics, and when I found StackOverflow, I learned a deal more through other people's answers (and resources that are sometimes mentioned). Then it's only about moving things around to suit what you want to do :)

Comment: Sabuj said this answer was perfect, so I will check this answer.  Really, it was both of you. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

You have two character class `[]` in your regex. Just place `*` and `?` character inside both the character class and it should work for you.

```
^\s*([0-9A-Fa-f*?]{1,2},\s*)*[0-9A-Fa-f*?]{1,2}\s*$
               ^^                      ^^
```

Comment: @User.1 Hmm, if you are okay with `0*, F?` being valid, then you can go for this one.

Comment: Wait a minute ! Sabuj, and Jerry too, you have both out thought me. This is indeed a superior answer to what I had originally conceived. the `F*` would be a great addition to the pattern. In fact, `F*` and `F?` could sortta'kinda mean the same thing, and give me more room on the matching criteria.  You can get a look at the context [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773975/verifying-user-input) Well duh again, I'm going to have to have both routines now; one to check my _SEND_ data and this one for the data the box returns. Great work guys !

Comment: Too bad I can't do `?F` and `*F`

Comment: @User.1 If you want to use a mix if the two regex for that particular purpose, then I suggest `@"^\s*([0-9A-F][0-9A-F*?]?)(,\s*([0-9A-F][0-9A-F*?]?)\s*)*$"`

Comment: @User.1 if you do not want to allow `?F`, `*F` in your input then just place `(?!.*[?*][a-zA-Z])` exactly after the `^` character in your regex. It means if there is no `?f`, `*a` matching in front.

Comment: No, I'd like to do both.  We want to give the other software a chance to match on bytes, and if we can get it down to the nybble level; that would be cool.  We're not going to the individual bit level.

Comment: ACK !  missed the 5 minute edit window. sorry.  I just tried that, and the test flunks `?F`.  Will get closer to this

Comment: Ignore, this line works:  `pattern = @"^\s*([0-9A-Fa-f*?]{1,2},\s*)*[0-9A-Fa-f*?]{1,2}\s*$";` and I am, once again, magnificent in the eyes of my coworkers. Thanks guys, thanks a lot. Both of you